# RecyclerView onClick Listener with firebase database ,Parcelable Implementation

Tags: android, parcelable

I would like to use the Parcelable implementation instead of the Serializable one:
**This is my class:**

```
public class Dentist implements Parcelable{
    private String Nom;
    private String Adresse;

    protected Dentist(Parcel in) {
        Nom = in.readString ( );
        Adresse = in.readString ( );
    }

    public Dentist(String nom, String adresse) {
        this.Nom = nom;
        this.Adresse = adresse;
    }

    public static final Creator<Dentist> CREATOR = new Creator<Dentist> ( ) {
        @Override
        public Dentist createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Dentist ( in );
        }

        @Override
        public Dentist[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Dentist[size];
        }
    };

    public String getNom() {
        return Nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        Nom = nom;
    }

    public String getAdresse() {
        return Adresse;
    }

    public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
        Adresse = adresse;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString ( Nom );
        dest.writeString ( Adresse );
    }
}
```

i send the object from " Liste activity " to "DetailsPage activity":

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View itemView) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), DetailsPage.class);

                        // get position
                        int pos = getAdapterPosition();

                        // check if item still exists
                        if(pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            Dentist clickedDataItem = listArray.get(pos);
                            intent.putExtra("nom",clickedDataItem.getNom ());
                            intent.putExtra("adresse",clickedDataItem.getAdresse ());
                            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "You clicked " + clickedDataItem.getNom(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
```

**In "DetailsPage activity" i get the object:**

```
DetailNom = (TextView)findViewById ( R.id.detail_nom );
        DetailsAdresse = (TextView)findViewById ( R.id.detail_adresse );
        DetailNom.setText ( "Nom :"+getIntent ().getParcelableExtra ( "nom" ) );
        DetailsAdresse.setText ( "Adresse :"+getIntent ().getParcelableExtra ( "adresse" ) );
```

**My Questions:**My app is stopped i don't know what's the problem? Where is the Error?
 I need Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
DetailNom = (TextView)findViewById ( R.id.detail_nom );
        DetailsAdresse = (TextView)findViewById ( R.id.detail_adresse );
        DetailNom.setText ( "Nom :"+getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "nom" ) );
        DetailsAdresse.setText ( "Adresse :"+getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "adresse" ) );
```

Comment: The Problem is rectified: the Error was that in my class missed a constructor with no arguments. Thanks